# Common connection class for project - struts 2.0

Tags: java, database, struts

How to make common connection pool class in struts ? for example in servlet and jsp I did

just connection class for making connection.

How can i do this in struts ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just like in j2se.You can crate a pool and use it. Or you can use utils to do the same thing. Like dbcp or c3p0. 
Good luck.